# I'm trying to make a submit type button that, when clicked on, redirects the user to another Razor type page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core

I tried a solution I saw online but the function they gave me seems to, when the button is pushed, it redirects to me again.

```
<div class="btn-block">
                <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" href="/">Send</button>
            </div>
```

This is how that button is written in html code.
The code in C# is this one:

```
protected IActionResult btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("L_page");
        }
```

My goal is to make the button, when clicked, redirect to a Razor page called L_page.
Can you give me some tips or another funcion to use?

Note:
I'm new at making websites and using ASP.NET so any other advice will be welcomed.

Comment: Do you use asp webform or mvc, my friend?

Comment: @Tomato32 I use ASP core Web Application

Answer (score 0):

**onclick** like that is a client-side thing, it will bind to a **javascript** function in the browser.  If that's what you want you could do this

```
<div class="btn-block">
                <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="clickHandlerInBrowser()">Send</button>
</div>
<script>
function clickHandlerInBrowser(){
   window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com"; //or e.g. "L-page.html"
}
</script>
```

Comment: as @Tomato32 says if you tell us if you are trying to use asp.net or aspnet core, and MVC or Razor Pages or webForms then people can help more. The c# code you have looks like an odd mix of syntax.

Comment: see javascript redirection https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp

Comment: But you maybe just want a link to another page, do you need to process form data on the server before redirecting?

Comment: I'm using core Web Application type project.

Comment: Is there any way of doing so with C# code?

Comment: Yes this is very do-able but --- do you need to get data from your first page back to the server to save it / process it at all? Or do you just want to take the user to another page?

Comment: second option m8

Comment: Sounds like you simply want an a tag e.g. `<a href="/somecontroller/someaction/123">link text</a>`

Comment: If you are just trying to get the user to another page, and don't need to process data from current page on the server - then just use a link (a tag) or if for style reasons it must be a button then see https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link.html

Comment: suggest using Google Chrome Dev Tools > network tab or Firefox equivalent, or Fiddler to check your http traffic if things not working out easily and you are not sure what's going on. Good luck.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network#:~:text=Open%20DevTools%20by%20pressing%20Control,The%20Console%20panel%20opens.&text=You%20might%20prefer%20to%20dock%20DevTools%20to%20the%20bottom%20of%20your%20window.&text=Click%20the%20Network%20tab. or https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: thank you for your help. Regarding the ```<a href="/somecontroller/someaction/123">link text</a>```can you put it in context? I'm only asking this because I don't know what is a controller in this context and also, what i should put in someaction

Comment: In case I need to get data from the first page to the second (L_page.cshtml), what would I need to do? Is there any way to do it with C#?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="btnSubmit" onclick="window.location.href='<%= Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName") %>';" />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net core mvc:

1.asp-controller,asp-action:

```
<a asp-controller="ControllerName" asp-action="ActionName">Send</a>
```

2.href:

```
<a href="/xxx/xxx">Send</a>
```

If you want to use button,you can also do like this:

```
<form asp-controller="ControllerName" asp-action="ActionName">
<button type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Send</button>
</form>
```

If you are using asp.net core razor page:

1.asp-page:

```
<a asp-page="../ControllerName/ActionName">Send</a>
```

Comment: Can you put it into context plz? I'm struggling to understand the xxx part.